# Isn't password storage designed to not un-mask passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-management

[Twitter revealed](https://twitter.com/TwitterSupport/status/992132808192634881?s=20) that its passwords got unmasked in internal logs. But correct me if I am wrong, passwords are never unmasked, right?

E.g. if the plaintext is "password", it is stored as "#masked". During authentication, "password" is masked to "#masked", and it is checked that masked==stored.

So how did some internal process end up unmasking them?

Comment: From [Twitter's blog](https://blog.twitter.com/official/en_us/topics/company/2018/keeping-your-account-secure.html), `Due to a bug, passwords were written to an internal log before completing the hashing process.` Although they don't provide details, often security equipment will log traffic in a manner such as this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I [speculated about the ways this could happen on my blog](https://systemoverlord.com/2018/05/03/how-the-twitter-and-github-password-logging-issues-could-happen.html), but the crux of the matter is that your password is received by the server as plaintext.  (Yes, it's in a TLS stream, but that's decrypted before being handed off to the application layer.)  It's very likely that some kind of debug code was accidentally enabled and resulting in logging the HTTP request, an RPC between microservices, or some other form of intermediate product.

It (likely) wasn't "let's log the password" but more like "let's log these serialized JSON requests to backend services" and one of those services happened to be the authentication backend.

Comment: the blog has a very nice demo sample

Answer (score 5):

It does not. The password is masked on the servers of Twitter, which means before they are masked, they are in plain-text. Twitter logged the passwords into the log before they got masked. Therefore the log contained the unmasked passwords.

Comment: so maybe something like log all HTTP Request went rogue?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Possibly, though I don't think Twitter is that silly. It was probably something more subtle/easier to miss, like an error dump.